# How can i delay reading posing in 3days for not logined user?

Tags: posts, users

```
if( ! is_user_logged_in() && ( in_category( 'test2' ) || in_category( 'test1' ) ) && ( current_time( 'Y-m-d' ) <= get_the_date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime('+3 days') ) ) ){ 
    echo 'sorry';
} else { 
    the_content(); 
}
```

my code in single.php loop. but not working. can i help anyone?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to show the post's content to logged out users, so you need to check that first. If the users were logged in, then check the category and their registration time:

```
if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    if( ( in_category( 'test2' ) || in_category( 'test1' ) ) && ( current_time( 'Y-m-d' ) <= get_the_date( 'Y-m-d' ) + strtotime('+3 days') ) ){
        echo "sorry";
    } else {
        the_content();
    }
} else {
    echo "sorry";
}
```

Comment: not working. maybe i was wrong code that get_the_date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime('+3 days')

Comment: I just reordered the conditional, but there is also a problem in your date function. change it to `get_the_date( 'Y-m-d' ) + strtotime('+3 days');`

Answer (score 0):

You're using `get_the_date()` wrong. That function gets the date of the post in a given format, and the 2nd argument is the Post ID for the post to get the date for. Not a time.

The simplest way to do this would be to just use timestamps. So you can just get the post date timestamp and add 3 days using the `DAY_IN_SECONDS` constant that WordPress provides:

```
if ( 
    ! is_user_logged_in() 
    && in_category( array( 'test2', 'test1' ) )
    && current_time( 'U' ) <= get_the_date( 'U' ) + ( 3 * DAY_IN_SECONDS )
) {
    echo 'Sorry';
} else {
        the_content();
    }
}
```

The key bit being:

```
current_time( 'U' ) <= get_the_date( 'U' ) + ( 3 * DAY_IN_SECONDS )
```

This should avoid issues with differences in timezones between `current_time()` and `strtotime()`.

PS: I also changed your multiple `in_category()` calls into a single call with an array.